# SQL - Rounding off numbers

Tags: sql, rounding, hour, minute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accuracy in rounding numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416762/accuracy-in-rounding-numbers)

I have the following requirement-

1. Get the A_MINUTES column value from TableA for all rows
2. Sum the A_MINUTES.
3. Convert the summed minutes values to hours - divide by 60
4. Round off the final hours value to 2 decimal places.

This needs to be written in SQL. Do you think the following query will have any rounding errors?

```
SELECT ROUND ( (SUM(A_MINUTES)/60.0) , 2) FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: Did your tests show any rounding errors?

Comment: In the future, do not delete your question when you find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If point 3.Sum the hours values to be considered you are missing one SUM function.

```
SELECT ROUND ( SUM(SUM(A_MINUTES)/60.0) , 2) FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: Actually, its just that I need to get the hours rounded off to 2 places. So, whether I (sum minutes and divide by 60) OR  (convert to hours and then sum it) - doesn't make a difference. :) I can make the edits to my post.